# Custom Angular (8) Pipe not found issue in Ionic 4 App

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have seen many questions like this on here but none seem to solve my issue as I think(?) I am doing this correctly - although its obvious I'm not.

I need to add a key to a URL in a gallery in an app I am working on so thought a custom pipe would do the trick. Using Ionic 4, my gallery.html contains:

```
            <ion-img cache="true" width="50%" [src]="i.ImageUrl | urlKey"></ion-img>
```

The url being piped to the 'urlKey' pipe where I can do stuff to it.
However, I am getting the error:

```
Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'urlKey' could not be found...
```

I created the pipe using Ionic command:

```
 ionic g pipe pipes/URLKey
```

.. and this created the blank pipe and added the declarations to my app.module.ts. Here's the Pipe, just set to return some text for now:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'urlKey'
})
export class URLKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    return 'hello';
 }
}
```

About as vanilla as it gets, and here's the app.module.ts:

```
... stuff above
import { URLKeyPipe } from './pipes/urlkey.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    URLKeyPipe,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  exports: [URLKeyPipe],   <- I added this export after reading about it on here, but that makes no difference.
 .... more stuff after
```

I also tried adding it to the gallery.module.ts, but then it found a duplicate declaration. I've checked the name is correct and that I think I am using it properly. Do I need to declare it somewhere else as well or what am I missing.
Thank you,
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using lazy loaded module for your gallery.

The template parser will recognize things like directives or components or pipes only if it was listed in the declaration array of the current ngModule (in your case Gallery) or if exported by another module which current module imports (if you would have shared pipes module imported by your gallery module).

Ionic 4 cli command added your pipe imports to the main module assuming you are using eagerly loaded modules.

So you need to either:

1. Only import the pipe by your gallery module (import and declaration)
2. If you plan to add more pipes or reuse pipe across the app - create a shared pipes module that exports pipes and that you could import into your gallery module.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, not sure of the approach I'll use yet, but adding it only to the Gallery module did the trick for now so Ive marked this as answer. Strange that there is no (obvuous) documentation about this anywhere I could see. Thanks again,Brett